# C programming: the cost of passing by value

Tags: c, memory-management, stack, pass-by-reference

I am learning C and get confused about something I read online.

At http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/stack/array/

I could read:

> Let's look at the functions that determine emptiness and fullness.
>   Now, it's not necessary to pass a stack by reference to these
>   functions, since they do not change the stack. So, we could prototype
>   them as:
>
> ```
> int StackIsEmpty(stackT stack);
> int StackIsFull(stackT stack);
> ```
>
> However, then some of the stack functions would take pointers (e.g.,
>   we need them for StackInit(), etc.) and some would not. It is more
>   consistent to just pass stacks by reference (with a pointer) all the
>   time

(I am not showing the code for what a stackT is, it is just a dynamic array)

From my (maybe limited) understanding, the disadvantage of passing by value is that the data is duplicated in the stack memory of the function. Since a stackT might be big, passing by value rather than pointer would be time consuming.

Do I get it right or am I still not clear with the basics ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, if you pass something "large" by value that item is copied onto the stack.

Passing *a pointer* to the data avoids the copy.

It is doubtful that the performance difference will be meaningful in most real-world applications, unless "large" is actually "huge" (which in turn may overflow the stack).

Comment: There is no pass by reference in C... It is still pass by value, but it is the value of the pointer

Comment: Just wondering, how can you ever pass something "large" by value? Even if you pass a statically allocated array, it will be passed through a pointer like `array[]`. And with a dynamically allocated array, you must pass a pointer to the function. The only thing I can think of is a structure with a lot of members...

Comment: This is off topic, but apparently if you have a statically allocated array in a structure, then the array is fully passed by value (i.e. fully copied in the function). This would probably be the easiest way to cause a stack overflow - by passing a structure with large statically allocated arrays by value.

Comment: @jucestain it is also commonly used for *returning* by-value arrays, though they're generally small.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you post a link to more info about return by-value arrays? It doesn't make sense to me why someone would do that, unless they need to make a copy of a static array inside a function maybe?

Comment: @jucestain I'll see if I can find something. The places I see it most is for convenience mostly, particularly for static variable initialization. The guarantee of predetermined vector magnitude seems to bring ease to some. But another reason would be the one you mentioned. Anyway, if I find what I consider to be a non-trivial sample I'll post it here.

Comment: I am beginner, but I really wonder if that would really make only little difference. In a stack, it is common to check if the structure is full or empty before each push or pop operation. In case of massive push/pop operations (what a stack do all the time), it seems difficult for me to believe that copying constantly the whole structure from heap memory to stack memory will not make large differences. But I lack experience to be confident in this.

Comment: @Vince: Most modern processors are highly optimized handling memory and stack operations.  It *is* slower to pass large things by value and I would avoid it in most cases, but it is still MUCH faster than other things a typical application does like access a file or database.

Comment: @Vince: Also, as you are a beginner and this is an interesting thing to learn, why not write two variants of a method implementation (one passing address by value, one passing structure by value) and benchmark the differences?  Should be a good learning experience.  Note if the method body does almost no work you will see a significant difference, but if the method body does any "real world" work load the difference should be much smaller.

Comment: @EricJ. Good advice, will try that ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Passing by value causes the program to copy, in the entirety, all of the data in that parameter. If it's only one or two ints, no problem, but copying multiple kilobytes is very expensive. Passing by reference only copies the pointer.
However, you must watch out for changing the data pointed at by the pointer and then expecting to return to it unchanged. C++ has passing by "const reference", which is like a guarantee that the data will not be changed, but C does not.

Comment: Even passing a few KB, while generally not good practice, is probably not "very expensive" compared to other costs in a typical application.

Comment: Honor the const-qualifier in C and you can enjoy the same benefit. `int StackIsEmpty(stackT const *stack)`